# Unable to read AndroidManiFest.xml Android Project

Tags: android

I am getting the following issue while trying to run an android project. Can anyone please suggest some solution to the problem?

```
Zip: EOCD not found, /data/local/tmp/Scrumptious.apk is not zip
06-26 21:25:53.012: D/asset(21420): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/Scrumptious.apk'
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/Scrumptious.apk
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:488)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:456)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:780)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:175)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/PackageParser(21420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-26 21:25:53.022: W/DefContainer(21420): Failed to parse package
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your apk is invalid(**Failed to parse package**), when the apk that's currently installed is differently signed. So try to

1. Uninstall the old application
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Rebuild the project
4. Reinstall the apk

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project-> Android Tools -> Fix project properties. Taken from the [developers page.](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html)

> If you see an error about AndroidManifest.xml, or some problems related to an Android zip file, right click on the project and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. (The project is looking in the wrong location for the library file, this will fix it for you.)